# Hacer un INSERT INTO usando un SELECT que contenga INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de hacer una inserción de datos en una tabla de un BD a partir de un SELECT TOP que tengo, mi SELECT TOP es el siguiente:

```
SELECT   TOP (100) PERCENT RTRIM(el.Id_Almacen) AS idalm, RTRIM(p.Id_Producto) AS codigo, p.Desc_Producto AS producto, p.UM_Almacen AS um, el.Seccion, el.Estante, el.Casilla, 
            el.Saldo_Existencia AS existe,
            p.Fecha_Entrada
FROM      Inventario.dbo.Producto AS p INNER JOIN
            Inventario.dbo.Existencia AS e ON e.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto INNER JOIN
            Inventario.dbo.Clasificacion_producto AS cp ON cp.Id_Clasificacion = e.Id_Clasificacion INNER JOIN
            Inventario.dbo.Existencia_Lotes AS el ON el.Id_Producto = e.Id_Producto AND el.Id_Almacen = e.Id_Almacen LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (SELECT   Id_Almacen, Id_Producto
                 FROM      Inventario.dbo.Submayor_Producto    
                 GROUP BY Id_Almacen, Id_Producto) AS mv ON mv.Id_Almacen = el.Id_Almacen AND mv.Id_Producto = el.Id_Producto
WHERE   (p.Producto_oServicio = 1)  AND (el.Saldo_Existencia <> 0)
ORDER BY p.Fecha_Entrada
```

y este es el resultado[image: resultado del select top]
mi idea es que en la nueva tabla que cree, llamada Producto_Listado me salgan los datos anteriores
[image: mi tabla producto listado vacia]
lo que no tengo idea de como modificar el codigo para que me haga lo que deseo

este es mi código insert

```
INSERT   TOP (100) PERCENT RTRIM(el.Id_Almacen) AS idalm, RTRIM(p.Id_Producto) AS codigo, p.Desc_Producto AS producto, p.UM_Almacen AS um, el.Seccion, el.Estante, el.Casilla, 
            el.Saldo_Existencia AS existe,
            p.Fecha_Entrada

            INTO Producto_Listado (pl.Id_Almacen, pl.Id_Producto,pl.Desc_Producto, pl.UM_Almacen, pl.Seccion, pl.Estante, pl.Casilla, pl.Saldo_Existencia, pl.Fecha_Entrada)
            
FROM      Inventario.dbo.Producto AS p INNER JOIN
            Inventario.dbo.Existencia AS e ON e.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto INNER JOIN
            Inventario.dbo.Clasificacion_producto AS cp ON cp.Id_Clasificacion = e.Id_Clasificacion INNER JOIN
            Inventario.dbo.Existencia_Lotes AS el ON el.Id_Producto = e.Id_Producto AND el.Id_Almacen = e.Id_Almacen LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (SELECT   Id_Almacen, Id_Producto
                 FROM      Inventario.dbo.Submayor_Producto    
                 GROUP BY Id_Almacen, Id_Producto) AS mv ON mv.Id_Almacen = el.Id_Almacen AND mv.Id_Producto = el.Id_Producto
WHERE   (p.Producto_oServicio = 1) AND (el.Saldo_Existencia <> 0)
ORDER BY p.Fecha_Entrada]
```

y este es el error que me da:
[image: error de insert]

Comment: ¿Por qué usas TOP para traer el 100% de las filas? ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes para usar `INSERT`?

Comment: @LuisCazares necesito tener el 100% de todas las filas para otras consultas que haré después en una aplicación java conectada a esa BD, mi problema con el instert lo pondré como una respuesta pq es demasiado largo para un comentario

Comment: @G.Torres mejor [edit] tu pregunta. Si respondes con mas código o explicando algo le pondrán votos negativos. Mejor edítala y pon todo lo que gustes.

Comment: Si necesitas traer el 100% de las filas, entonces no necesitas un TOP. No agregues información de tu pregunta como respuesta, en vez de eso edita tu pregunta.

Comment: @LuisCazares que me recomiendas hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo comenté, no necesitas usar el TOP(100) PERCENT puesto que pide que use todas las filas y ese es el comportamiento por default. La sintaxis del INSERT está incorrecta y por eso te marca el error. La sintaxis correcta la encuentras en [la ayuda de SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Fuera de eso, hay varias prácticas no recomendadas en el código. Dejo comentarios en el ejemplo.

```
INSERT INTO Producto_Listado(
    Id_Almacen, 
    Id_Producto,
    Desc_Producto, 
    UM_Almacen, 
    Seccion, 
    Estante, 
    Casilla, 
    Saldo_Existencia, 
    Fecha_Entrada
)    
SELECT
    RTRIM(el.Id_Almacen) AS idalm, 
    RTRIM(p.Id_Producto) AS codigo, 
    p.Desc_Producto AS producto, 
    p.UM_Almacen AS um, 
    el.Seccion, 
    el.Estante, 
    el.Casilla, 
    el.Saldo_Existencia AS existe,
    p.Fecha_Entrada
FROM       Inventario.dbo.Producto               AS p 
INNER JOIN Inventario.dbo.Existencia             AS e  ON e.Id_Producto       = p.Id_Producto 
INNER JOIN Inventario.dbo.Clasificacion_producto AS cp ON cp.Id_Clasificacion = e.Id_Clasificacion 
INNER JOIN Inventario.dbo.Existencia_Lotes       AS el ON el.Id_Producto      = e.Id_Producto 
                                                      AND el.Id_Almacen       = e.Id_Almacen 
-- Código comentado porque no hace nada
--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT    DISTINCT Id_Almacen, Id_Producto
--                 FROM      Inventario.dbo.Submayor_Producto) AS mv ON mv.Id_Almacen = el.Id_Almacen AND mv.Id_Producto = el.Id_Producto
WHERE p.Producto_oServicio =  1 
AND   el.Saldo_Existencia  <> 0;
--ORDER BY p.Fecha_Entrada] -- El orden no importa al insertar datos
```